# Can i ask if an answer to a puzzle is right?

Tags: discussion

I found a puzzle on another site that I thought was  really educational and interesting. So I gave the puzzle to my young kids, just to get them thinking. I promised them a big reward if they found a valid answer, knowing that there was nearly zero chance of them working it out, but I wanted to motivate them to think about it. I was wrong! They came back with an original answer after a day, but I can't work out if it is valid or not. I would like to present the puzzle and my kids' answer, and ask for a consensus if the answer is a valid one or not. Can I do this? If so what tag? Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s nothing inherently wrong with posting a question about a puzzle here, as opposed to challenging people to solve it.  In fact, the site originally consisted exclusively of questions *about* puzzles and their creation and solving.  I’d offer a few thoughts.

1. If you don’t know the actual answer to a puzzle and/or you just want our opinion on whether or not your kids’ answer is a valid solution, if we can’t definitively work out the correct answer ourselves then we’re just *guessing* if your kids’ answer is right. This makes your question ***primarily opinion based***, and will likely end up closed for that reason.  Most sites that post puzzles also provide their solutions, so make sure you’ve looked for that first.
2. If you know “**the** answer” and you want to know if your kids’ solution is also valid (or why it isn't), we might be able to point out why the intended answer is a better fit and/or why the puzzle rules out their solution.... or we might not. That all depends on the quality of the original puzzle itself.  If we can’t then you’re again asking for our opinion, and your question will unfortunately probably be closed for being *primarily opinion based*.
3. You’ve found a question online somewhere else and want to post it here.  [Can I post a puzzle I found on the internet?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6221) is at least partially relevant here.  Quick summary: make sure you’re allowed to repost the other site’s content, provide proper attribution, and in general don’t post unremarkable puzzles and/or stuff you can find on multiple sites because chances are good then that most of us have already seen it or its like several times before and it isn’t going to make for an appealing puzzle here.
4. Tags are mostly tied to the kind of puzzle, and we don’t really have one for “is this answer right?”  So how you should tag it depends on what the puzzle is.

It’s great that you’re encouraging your kids to exercise their minds in more abstract ways! It strengthens problem solving skills and encourages thinking about information they’re given in unobvious ways, skills that can definitely be useful later in life. Feel free to explore here as well. Perhaps look through some of the more [highly voted puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq) and see which ones are most appealing to you, and then look into the tags for those kinds of puzzles and find more puzzles with which to challenge your kids.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I agree puzzles are wonderful things. The benefits are untold. They help with almost everything I can think of. As beneficial as daily walks or other physical exercise. I will add my question in the main site.